# 'rake' "in order to" 'rake'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

To prepare database for my Ruby on Rails 3 application I need to run the following steps in the Terminal:

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

**Is it possible to do all those steps in one?** Maybe it is possible running a 'rake' command that will "fire" another 'rake' command... but how?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own rake tasks which call other tasks as prerequisites:

```
# lib/tasks/my_tasks.rake
namespace :db do
  desc "create, migrate and seed"
  task :do_all => [:create,:migrate,:seed] do
  end
end
```

Normally the body of the task would contain Ruby code to do something, but in this case we are just invoking the three prerequisite tasks in turn (`db:create`,`db:migrate`,`db:seed`).

Comment: It doesn't work: "rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'db:do_all'".

Comment: Oops, I goofed in the example. Rake tasks belong in files suffixed with `.rake`. Put the task in (eg) `./lib/tasks/my_tasks.rake`. Verify with `rake -T db` -- you should see your task listed.

Answer (score 3):

The empty do-end blocks are not needed, e.g. (for zetetic's answer)

```
$ cat lib/tasks/my_tasks.rake
# lib/tasks/my_tasks.rake
namespace :db do
  desc "create, migrate and seed"
  task :do_all => [:create,:migrate,:seed] 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`rake db:create db:migrate db:seed` will do all that.

Answer (score 1):

zeteitic got it right, but in the event you don't want to namespace this task under "db", you'd want something more like this:

```
desc "Bootstrap database."
task :bootstrap => ["db:create", "db:migrate", "db:seed"] do; end
```

And on the command line:

```
rake bootstrap
# => create, migrate and seed db
```

Comment: In the terminal the 'rake bootstrap' command will result as a "rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'bootstrap'" error.